# How can we check whether connected network connection is reachable or not in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, networking

My app supports iOS12 or later and i am using latest macOS and xcode. I did several research on this topic but couldn't found any proper solutions. Yes, i know how to check whether we are connected to the network or not and can get connection types too. But the problem is: is my connected network reachable? I am communicating with an IoT device, and i have to get some data from it, also send it to different server. That device always gives me the data because it is an intranet, as i am connected to it's hotspot. I have to check whether it can send data further on it's own to another remote server(sometimes network connection doesn't work) or if not i need to switch wifi connection to my local network. I have tried several ways but couldn't get satisfactory results.

Comment: If you can send the api request, it is working otherwise it is not. Why do you need to know this beforehand and what does "working" really mean, it's a really vague requirement.

Comment: i am communicating with an IoT device, i have to get some data from it and send it to different server. the device always gives me the data because it is an intranet, as i am connected to it's hotspot. i have to check whether it can send data further on it's own to another server(sometimes network connection doesn't work) or i need to switch wifi connection to my local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to just try: invoke the network request and check the result. What you do if you got an error depends on your use case, if there is a user involved or if the request was made in the background.

For example, you may just output an error and let the user proceed in the app. This may require to design your screen accordingly, i.e. provide a way where the user can retry it (in the screen where you show the content, show an empty content screen and provide a pull-to-refresh or a "retry" button, etc.).

Or, you may analyse the kind of error (URL error or response error) and may apply several strategies. For example, if the network request can be performed in the background you may apply a retry when you got a 5xx HTTP status. Or, if the connection was lost (no response and you get an URLError) you may start to observe the network state and retry when the network is available.

Answer (score 3):

What *@Joakim Danielson* said above is what you should be doing. No matter what source you use, it will always give you false information at some point (about being connected to internet or not).

1. Make the api call.
2. Check for errors - is it a temporary network error?
3. Make the call on whether you should retry or show something else to user.

#### How to check if it might be a temporary network error?

You can use this extension on `NSError` instance that was returned from api call.

```
public extension NSError {
    
    var isConnectionAborted: Bool {
        return (self.domain == NSPOSIXErrorDomain && self.code == 53)
    }
    
    var isTemporaryNetworkError: Bool {
        let temporaryNetworkErrorCodes = [
            NSURLErrorTimedOut,
            NSURLErrorCannotFindHost,
            NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost,
            NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost,
            NSURLErrorDNSLookupFailed,
            NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects,
            NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable,
            NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet,
            NSURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation,
            NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed,
            NSURLErrorCannotLoadFromNetwork,
            NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted,
        ]
        
        return (self.isConnectionAborted || temporaryNetworkErrorCodes.contains(self.code))
    }
    
    var isCancelled: Bool {
        return (self.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && self.code == NSURLErrorCancelled)
    }

}
```

---

#### I tried an api call, it failed, now I want to query whether I'm connected to ineternet or not. How to know?

Somewhere in your API code, you can add an observer for possible network changes by using [NWPathMonitor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor) like this - requires `iOS 12`

```
import Network

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor"))
monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { (path) in
    if path.status == .satisfied {
        print("Connected")
    } else {
        print("Not Connected")
    }
}
```

This allows more granular control as well `.cellular`, `.wifi` & `.wiredEthernet` etc. -

```
let cellMonitor = NWPathMonitor(requiredInterfaceType: .cellular)
```

---

If you still support `iOS 11`, you can use a 3rd party library like - [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)